# How to download with wget or curl?

Tags: downloads, protocol

With simple `wget -c`  or `curl -O` no download (timeout!), but I see as a normal page in my *browser*,

http://www.planalto.gov.br/CCivil_03/leis/2002/L10406compilada.htm

so, how to download it by *basic sdandard commands at terminal*?

The time to download and the content (a big HTML file) **MUST** be the same as I see in my *browser*.

---

PS: this URL is a typical case where response to a "non-usual agent request" is not the same tham a popular browser request... But the page  is a official text of law, so needs access without barriers, need to be frictionless: there are a RFC (or W3C recomendarion, or similar) suggesting or classifying whats is "HTTP frictionless access"?

Comment: If you download an html page, you'll get and html page. What else do you expect?

Comment: What do you want to download from the page? An HTML page?

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever, I edited... And I can **delete this question** if you deem it necessary: it is a simple and obvious problem/solution.

Comment: The good question, about open data, is at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/12315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with many alternatives... The "minimal extra-header" (required by server to offer the correct content) is `User-Agent`. With it is working fine:

```
curl -O -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux)" \
   http://www.planalto.gov.br/CCivil_03/leis/2002/L10406compilada.htm
```

... It is an official old service and "bad HTML", neither HTML source neither HTTP headers (`-v` option) shows the enconding (that is not standard UTF-8). The complete solution is

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux)" \
   http://www.planalto.gov.br/CCivil_03/leis/2002/L10406compilada.htm \
   | iconv -c  -t UTF-8  -f ISO-8859-1 > L10406compilada.htm
```